# Making iOS two finger swipe similar to apple's four finger swipe to toggle between apps

Tags: ios, ipad, core-animation, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Hi all we all know iOS four finger swipe to toggle between apps

[image]

I am planning to do something similar, when I do a two finger swipe I will be doing the same thing as the four finger swipe but within  the app i.e, I will be toggling between two view controllers and this should be animated, both view controllers should be visible during the swipe.[image] **So basically there would be two mini apps inside the app and the user should be able to toggle between them at any point.**

I am trying something, meanwhile share your thoughts if you have tried or done something like this. I am using complex gestures inside the app too so this gesture recognition should not conflict with others.

Code I am trying now

```
-(void)addSwipeToToggle
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *toggleSwipe=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenToggled)];
    toggleSwipe.minimumNumberOfTouches=2;
    toggleSwipe.maximumNumberOfTouches=3;
    [self.window addGestureRecognizer:toggleSwipe];
}

-(void)screenToggled
{
    UIViewController *dummyController=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    dummyController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    self.window.rootViewController=dummyController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: So where is the question?  Is this asking about design ( sure why not), implementation ( straightforward and obvious I would think) or what?

Comment: I want to implement such a thing in my app, pan to toggle between two view controllers.

Comment: So what is stopping you? I don't see a question in there, just a request..

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I am trying to do that, if I was able to do it I would have done it. I wanted to ask whether any one has done such a thing before.

Comment: Something like `UIPageViewController` with `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I saw UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll but I saw this property NSArray *gestureRecognizers // Only populated if transition style is UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl' but I want this style UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll.

Comment: @satheeshwaran FYI, `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` only works in iOS 6 and above. If you need iOS 5 compatible solution, you'll have to do it your own custom container view controller (e.g. something like [Navigating UIViewControllers with gestures in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703613/navigating-uiviewcontrollers-with-gestures-in-ios/15747892#15747892)) or, even simpler, forgo continuous gestures and just do slide animation segues on standard segues.

Comment: @Rob Yes I get you UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll is supported from iOS 6. I saw your link it is good, will try something like that.